# Header styling on a DataGrid in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I know this question looks like it has been asked before, but this one has a twist....

Who can suggest why this header styling on my datagrid does everything as it should except wrap the text.

```
            // Setup the Header Style to use on certain of the column headers, centered horizontally and vertically, in bold font, with text wrapping
        System.Windows.Style HeaderStyle = new Style();
        HeaderStyle.Setters.Add(new System.Windows.Setter
        {
            Property = FontSizeProperty,
            Value    = 12.0
        });
        HeaderStyle.Setters.Add(new System.Windows.Setter
        {
            Property = System.Windows.Controls.Control.HorizontalAlignmentProperty,
            Value    = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch
        });
        HeaderStyle.Setters.Add(new System.Windows.Setter
        {
            Property = System.Windows.Controls.Control.HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty,
            Value    = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        });
        HeaderStyle.Setters.Add(new System.Windows.Setter
        {
            Property = FontWeightProperty,
            Value    = FontWeights.Bold
        });
        HeaderStyle.Setters.Add(new System.Windows.Setter
        {
            Property = TextBlock.TextWrappingProperty,
            Value    = TextWrapping.Wrap
        });
```

This is how I use it:

```
            // Add the Backup Paths Total Column
        DataGridTemplateColumn  TotalTextColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        FrameworkElementFactory TotalTextBorder = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(EMSTextCell));
        FrameworkElementFactory TotalTextBlock  = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
        ImageTemplate = new DataTemplate();

        TotalTextColumn.CellTemplate = ImageTemplate;

        TotalTextColumn.Header      = EMS_Config_Tool.Properties.Resources.BackupPaths_BackupPaths;
        TotalTextColumn.HeaderStyle = HeaderStyle;
        TotalTextColumn.Width       = new DataGridLength(100);
        TotalTextColumn.CanUserSort = false;
```

...

If you know why it doesn't work, can you also suggest what I can do to make it work! Maybe there is some other property to use, or perhaps some of my properties are mutually exclusive? (PS - I'm not keen on a XAML solution, I have a few different types of columns in this grid with very different header types and properties)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `TextWrapping.WrapWithOverflow`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `TextBlock.TextWrappingProperty` is not inheriting its value. You can check this with:

```
var pm1 = TextBlock.TextWrappingProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(TextBlock)) as FrameworkPropertyMetadata;
if (pm1 != null)
{
    var test = pm1.Inherits; // false
}
```

So, even though the property is set on `DataGridColumnHeader`, it is not set on the inner `TextBlock`. So if you want wrapping, you need a style resource targeting `TextBlock` or just define the `Header` as an explicit textblock:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.Header>
    <TextBlock Text="aaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbb cccccccccc ddddddddd" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</DataGridTextColumn.Header>
```

or in code

```
TotalTextColumn.Header = new TextBlock() { Text = TextBlockEMS_Config_Tool.Properties.Resources.BackupPaths_BackupPaths, TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap };
```

Comment: Brilliant - thanks, that works a treat. The issue was that the English text was fine, but in French and Spanish the titles are a lot more verbose so they overflowed the single line available.